# Adding Firebase as dependency in my own created pod

Tags: ios, firebase, cocoapods

I have a pod that needs firebase

Whenever I add

```
spec.dependency 'Firebase/Analytics'
spec.dependency 'Firebase/Database'
```

It work, tho it has a runtime error, it's asking for the google plist. How do I attach the plist to my pod?

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed these steps and added firebase pList in project?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup

Comment: Yes I did but which of it are u referring to exactly? I created an example app also that has a podfile ```pod 'MyCustomPod', path: "../"``` after running it still ask for my google plist even if it's inside of the custom pod

Comment: Follow the Step 1,2 and 3 in step three there is mentioned about pLIst 

[1]Click Download GoogleService-Info.plist to obtain your Firebase iOS config file (GoogleService-Info.plist).

You can download your Firebase iOS config file again at any time.


[2]Move your config file into the root of your Xcode project. If prompted, select to add the config file to all targets.

Comment: I want the google plist to be in my pod only is that possible? So whenever such user imports my custom pod firebase within my pod will still work together with firebase

Comment: Yes , create firebase account and proceed till download pList , you will get the Keys in pList which you need to add in code to use Firebase API and please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Each app needs to have its own `GoogleService-Info.plist`.

Instructions for using your pod should reference instructions for each client to create and build their own `GoogleService-Info.plist`.